# How can there be a horizontal impulse applied to a sphere?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation

"Suppose a problem says that there is a solid sphere is rolling without slipping , suddenly a horizontal impulse(not along the midway diameter line) is applied on it and problem says to find some stuff" , but thats not my issue , my query is how can a horizontal impulse be given to a sphere as such on sphere normal force acting would be always normal to sphere at that point so it cant be a horizontal impulse unless its acting along the midway line of diameter ? [image]

Comment: Ever played billiards or pool?

Comment: Not all contact forces are normal forces

Comment: By FBD or some setup may you explain how is it possible to give a horizontal impulse and i have not played those except online Sir :(

Comment: There is some friction so that the sphere supports also tangential components of forces.

Comment: Thanks @Valter Moretti got it now